# Customize Self Registration page on Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

We are using Self Registration page on Community Builder.We want to make a custom field mandatory in user object on user sign up.Where can i customize?.Please advise on this.

[image: Sign Up Form]

Comment: are you doing it using visual-force page. ?
if yes, then populate the field using field-set and make the field required in field-set. If not field-set, make them directly required at  visual-force page using `required=true` at apex:inputField.

Comment: Thanks @Ankuli I've already made the field as required.. Still I'm facing the issue.. And also I need to check whether the highlighted input box has value starting with 'ÁA' on User Sign Up

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the builder takes value from the fieldsets .You can easily make field required in the fieldset

[image]

There is a custom  lightning component(Which is present in sandbox) that can be customized futher .Here is a sample code from one of my orgs

```
<aura:component controller="LightningSelfRegisterController">   
<aura:attribute name="extraFieldsFieldSet" type="String" required="false" description="A field set name whose fields are desired for user registration"/> <!--Make it true here -->
<aura:attribute name="extraFields" type="list" required="false" description="A field set name whose fields are desired for user registration"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohith I've already made the field as required.. Still I'm facing the issue.. And also I need to check whether the highlighted input box has value starting with 'ÁA' on User Sign Up.. Please advise me where I can customize the Self Register Page.

Comment: Might be a bug then that needs to be addressed .There will be a lightning component that comes as an example .Please customize that

Comment: @ Mohith I have got only CommunitiesSelfRegController and not the LightningSelfRegisterController. Not sure how only LightningForgotPasswordController alone got created. How should I make this controller appear for editing? Lightning experience is also enabled for this org.

Comment: Create a simple Developer org and enable communities that will give you the code as well .Hope that helps